# Multiple IO effects in Eff (or other ways for composable effects)

Tags: haskell

I want to restrict effects of functions in my program as much as possible so that
e.g. if I have a function that's supposed to query a DB I know it won't be
printing stuff for deleting my files.

As a concrete example let's say I have a database with a "users" table.

Some of the functions only read this table, some of the functions read and write.

With mtl and transformers I can try something like this:

```
data User = User { username :: String }
  deriving (Show)

class Monad m => ReadDb m where
  getUsers      :: m [User]
  getUserByName :: String -> m (Maybe User)

class Monad m => WriteDb m where
  addUser    :: String -> m ()
  removeUser :: String -> m Bool
```

However implementing the instances I need is tricky, if not impossible. To be
able to access the DB I need a `SqlBackend` and IO:

```
data SqlBackend

instance (MonadReader SqlBackend m, MonadIO m, Monad m) => ReadDb m where
  getUsers = undefined
  getUserByName = undefined

instance (MonadReader SqlBackend m, MonadIO m, Monad m) => WriteDb m where
  addUser = undefined
  removeUser = undefined
```

With `UndecidableInstances` this works fine. However, let's say I also need
logging, and no, I won't collect log strings in a `[String]` or anything like
that. The logger should efficiently log, and logging messages should appear in
real time.

So I may do something like this:

```
class Monad m => Log m where
  log :: String -> m ()
```

Logging needs a `Logger`, so I may define an instance like

```
data Logger

instance (MonadReader Logger m, MonadIO m, Monad m) => Log m where
  log = undefined
```

Now a function that reads the db and logs would look like this:

```
logUsers :: (ReadDb m, Log m) => m ()
logUsers = getUsers >>= log . show
```

But unfortunately I can't really run this because I need to provide
`MonadReader SqlBackend m` and `MonadReader Logger m`, which is not possible
because of the functional dependency `MonadReader r m | m -> r`.

There are workarounds (like implementing a different typeclass just to get
`Logger` and `SqlBackend`), but they involve too much boilerplate.

As an alternative I wanted to try Oleg's extensible effect library (the Eff
monad, implemented here http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/Eff.hs). The
trouble is, as far as I understand, multiple effects that need to be handled in
IO can't be implemented in a composable way in `Eff`. For example, the `Trace`
effect in the library is implemented like this:

```
data Trace

runTrace :: Eff (Trace :> Void) w -> IO w
```

`Void` part is the problem here. In my example I want to handle read, write and
logging operations separately, and functions should be able to have
fine-grained types that allow any subset of these effects.

One thing comes to mind here is `Free`, but I'm not sure how to define functors
for these effects, and then compose them so that for example a function that
logs will be able to call another function that doesn't log but otherwise has
same effects.

So my question is: How do I get fine-grained effect types in my program, with
effect handlers that actually compose. Effect handlers should be able to run in
IO. Let's say performance is not a concern (so `Free` etc. is OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benjamin's answer shows how to do this with mtl, which is helpful, but I actually asked for an `Eff` solution, so here it is:

(code inspired by the answer given in `freer` issue tracker: https://gitlab.com/queertypes/freer/issues/7)

We have 4 type of effects:

- Write output to stdout
- Read input from stdin
- Read a db
- Log to a handle

Here's a solution that uses `extensible-effects`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators         #-}

module GetlinePutline where

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import           Control.Eff
import           Control.Eff.Lift
import           Data.Typeable
import           Prelude          hiding (log)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data Getline v = Getline (String -> v)
  deriving (Typeable, Functor)

getline :: Member Getline r => Eff r String
getline = send (inj (Getline id))

runGetline :: (SetMember Lift (Lift IO) r) => Eff (Getline :> r) w -> Eff r w
runGetline = freeMap return (\u -> handleRelay u runGetline (\(Getline k) -> lift getLine >>= runGetline . k))

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data Putline v = Putline String (() -> v)
  deriving (Typeable, Functor)

putline :: Member Putline r => String -> Eff r ()
putline s = send (inj (Putline s id))

runPutline :: (SetMember Lift (Lift IO) r) => Eff (Putline :> r) w -> Eff r w
runPutline = freeMap return (\u -> handleRelay u runPutline (\(Putline s k) -> lift (putStrLn s) >>= runPutline . k))

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Similar to Putline, but we provide a logger when running

data Logger

defaultLogger :: Logger
defaultLogger = undefined

logToHandle :: Logger -> String -> IO ()
logToHandle _ s = putStrLn ("logging: " ++ show s)

-- Log using a logger
data Log v = Log String (() -> v)
  deriving (Typeable, Functor)

log :: Member Log r => String -> Eff r ()
log s = send (inj (Log s id))

runLog :: SetMember Lift (Lift IO) r => Logger -> Eff (Log :> r) w -> Eff r w
runLog logger = freeMap return (\u -> handleRelay u (runLog logger) (\(Log s k) -> lift (logToHandle logger s) >>= runLog logger . k))

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Database read

data User = User { username :: String }
  deriving (Show)

data ReadDb v
  = GetUsers ([User] -> v)
  | GetUserByUsername String (Maybe User -> v)
  deriving (Typeable, Functor)

getUsers :: Member ReadDb r => Eff r [User]
getUsers = send (inj (GetUsers id))

getUserByUsername :: Member ReadDb r => String -> Eff r (Maybe User)
getUserByUsername uname = send (inj (GetUserByUsername uname id))

data SqlBackend = SqlBackend

getUsers_db :: SqlBackend -> IO [User]
getUsers_db _ = return [User "user1"]

getUserByUsername_db :: SqlBackend -> String -> IO (Maybe User)
getUserByUsername_db _ uname = return (Just (User uname))

runReadDb :: SetMember Lift (Lift IO) r => SqlBackend -> Eff (ReadDb :> r) w -> Eff r w
runReadDb db = freeMap return (\u -> handleRelay u (runReadDb db) (\case GetUsers k -> lift (getUsers_db db) >>= runReadDb db . k
                                                                         GetUserByUsername s k -> lift (getUserByUsername_db db s) >>= runReadDb db . k))

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

myEff :: (Member Log r, Member Putline r, Member Getline r, Member ReadDb r) => Eff r ()
myEff = do
  ln <- getline
  putline ln
  putline "done"
  log "logging stuff"
  putline "reading db"
  users <- getUsers
  log (show users)

main :: IO ()
main = runLift $ runLog defaultLogger $ runPutline $ runGetline $ runReadDb SqlBackend myEff
```

Solution using `freer`:

```
-- originally posted to https://gitlab.com/queertypes/freer/issues/7
-- modified to remove IO from myEff

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators         #-}

module GetlinePutline where

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import           Control.Monad.Freer
import           Control.Monad.Freer.Internal
import           Prelude                      hiding (log)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

doIO :: Member IO r => IO a -> Eff r a
doIO = send

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data Getline a where
  Getline :: Getline String

getline :: Member Getline r => Eff r String
getline = send Getline

runGetline :: Member IO r => Eff (Getline ': r) w -> Eff r w
runGetline (Val x) = return x
runGetline (E u q) = case decomp u of
  Right Getline -> doIO getLine >>= runGetline . qApp q
  Left u1       -> E u1 (tsingleton (runGetline . qApp q))

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data Putline a where
  Putline :: String -> Putline ()

runPutline :: Member IO r => Eff (Putline ': r) w -> Eff r w
runPutline (Val x) = return x
runPutline (E u q) = case decomp u of
  Right (Putline s) -> doIO (putStrLn s) >> runPutline (qApp q ())
  Left u1           -> E u1 (tsingleton (runPutline . qApp q))

putline :: Member Putline r => String -> Eff r ()
putline = send . Putline

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Similar to Putline, but we provide a logger when running

data Logger

defaultLogger :: Logger
defaultLogger = undefined

logToHandle :: Logger -> String -> IO ()
logToHandle _ s = putStrLn ("logging: " ++ show s)

-- Log using a logger
data Log a where
  Log :: String -> Log ()

log :: Member Log r => String -> Eff r ()
log = send . Log

runLog :: Member IO r => Logger -> Eff (Log ': r) w -> Eff r w
runLog _      (Val x) = return x
runLog logger (E u q) = case decomp u of
  Right (Log s) -> doIO (logToHandle logger s) >> runLog logger (qApp q ())
  Left u1       -> E u1 (tsingleton (runLog logger . qApp q))

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Database read

data User = User { username :: String }
  deriving (Show)

data ReadDb a where
  GetUsers          :: ReadDb [User]
  GetUserByUsername :: String -> ReadDb (Maybe User)

getUsers :: Member ReadDb r => Eff r [User]
getUsers = send GetUsers

getUserByUsername :: Member ReadDb r => String -> Eff r (Maybe User)
getUserByUsername = send . GetUserByUsername

data SqlBackend = SqlBackend

getUsers_db :: SqlBackend -> IO [User]
getUsers_db _ = return [User "user1"]

getUserByUsername_db :: SqlBackend -> String -> IO (Maybe User)
getUserByUsername_db _ uname = return (Just (User uname))

runReadDb :: Member IO r => SqlBackend -> Eff (ReadDb ': r) w -> Eff r w
runReadDb _  (Val x) = return x
runReadDb db (E u q) = case decomp u of
  Right GetUsers -> doIO (getUsers_db db) >>= runReadDb db . qApp q
  Right (GetUserByUsername uname) -> doIO (getUserByUsername_db db uname) >>= runReadDb db . qApp q
  Left u1 -> E u1 (tsingleton (runReadDb db . qApp q))

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

myEff :: (Member Log r, Member Putline r, Member Getline r, Member ReadDb r) => Eff r ()
myEff = do
  ln <- getline
  putline ln
  putline "done"
  log "logging stuff"
  putline "reading db"
  users <- getUsers
  log (show users)

main :: IO ()
main = runM $ runLog defaultLogger $ runPutline $ runGetline $ runReadDb SqlBackend myEff
```

Answer (score 5):

I think your `instance` declaration is a mistake.

```
instance (MonadReader SqlBackend m, MonadIO m, Monad m) => ReadDb m
```

This instance will match *all* type constructors `m :: * -> *`, and then later fail if the `m` in question doesn't fit the instance context. There's no backtracking in instance search. In other words, you can't change out instances of `ReadDb` (like, if you need to mock out the database during testing). It also leads to your problem with overlapping superclasses.

It's better to structure your program as a monad transformer stack, using `newtype`s as usual. So I'm going to write down a custom monad transformer:

```
data SqlConfig = SqlConfig { connectionString :: String }

newtype DbT m a = DbT (ReaderT SqlConfig m a) deriving (
    Functor,
    Applicative,
    Alternative,
    Monad,
    MonadTrans,
    MonadPlus,
    MonadFix,
    MonadIO,
    MonadWriter w,
    MonadState s,
    MonadError e,
    MonadCont
    )
runDbT :: DbT m a -> SqlConfig -> m a
runDbT (DbT m) = runReaderT m
```

I'm using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to derive the `mtl` classes *except for `MonadReader`*. (These instances also require `UndecidableInstances` because they fail the coverage condition.) I don't want to lift the `MonadReader` instance from the `ReaderT` inside the `DbT`, I want to lift it from the base monad. `DbT` is not `ReaderT`, it just happens to be implemented using `ReaderT`.

```
mapDbT :: (m a -> n b) -> DbT m a -> DbT n b
mapDbT f (DbT m) = DbT $ mapReaderT f m
instance MonadReader r m => MonadReader r (DbT m) where
    ask = lift ask
    local = mapDbT . local
```

And I can implement your classes using `DbT` as long as we have access to `IO`:

```
instance MonadIO m => MonadReadDb (DbT m) where
    getUsers = DbT $ ask >>= (liftIO . query "select * from Users")
    getUserByName name = DbT $ ask >>= (liftIO . query "select * from Users where Name = @name")

instance MonadIO m => MonadWriteDb (DbT m) where
    addUser u = DbT $ ask >>= (liftIO . query "insert Users (Name) values @name")
    removeUser u = DbT $ ask >>= (liftIO . query "delete Users where Name = @name")
```

Likewise, I can set up a logging monad transformer:

```
data LoggingConfig = LoggingConfig { filePath :: String }

newtype LoggerT m a = LoggerT (ReaderT LoggingConfig m a) deriving (
    Functor,
    Applicative,
    Alternative,
    Monad,
    MonadTrans,
    MonadPlus,
    MonadFix,
    MonadIO,
    MonadWriter w,
    MonadState s,
    MonadError e,
    MonadCont
    )
runLoggerT :: LoggerT m a -> LoggingConfig -> m a
runLoggerT (LoggerT m) = runReaderT m

instance MonadIO m => MonadLogger (LoggerT m) where
    log msg = LoggerT $ do
        config <- ask
        liftIO $ writeFile (filePath config) msg

-- MonadReader instance omitted. It's identical to the DbT instance
```

Annoyingly - and this is the main downside of the `mtl` approach - you have to write O(n^2) instances to make these types compose nicely.

```
instance MonadLogger m => MonadLogger (DbT m) where
    log = lift . log

instance MonadReadDb m => MonadReadDb (LoggerT m) where
    getUsers = lift getUsers
    getUserByName = lift . getUserByName

instance MonadWriteDb m => MonadWriteDb (LoggerT m) where
    addUser = lift . addUser
    removeUser = lift . removeUser

-- and a bunch of identical instances for all the types in transformers
```

You can write monadic programs using your three classes, as usual:

```
myProgram :: (MonadLogger m, MonadReadDb m, MonadWriteDb m) => m ()
myProgram = do
    us <- getUsers
    log $ "removing " ++ show (length us) ++ " users"
    void $ traverse removeUser us
```

Then at the entry point to your program, when you build and run your monad transformer stack, you just unwrap your `LoggerT` and `DbT` newtypes and supply the required config.

```
runProgram :: LoggerT (DbT IO) a -> LoggingConfig -> SqlConfig -> IO a
runProgram m l s = runDbT (runLoggerT m l) s

ghci> :t runProgram myProgram
runProgram myProgram :: LoggingConfig -> SqlConfig -> IO ()
```

Comment: Good point re: no backtracking in instance search. Implementing transformers in addition to mtl-style classes seem to work (and I actually hinted at this solution in my question), but can I make this work using Eff too? Thanks btw.

Comment: @sinan Making it work with extensible effects is not too hard once you already have this code, since regular `Monad`s are effects: e.g. `Eff '[ LoggerT IO, DbT IO, IO] x` is a valid effect. Your 'runners' for these effects (i.e. effects which use `IO` or any other monad which isn't a transformer as a 'base' monad) can have type `Member IO r => Eff (M ': r) x -> Eff r x` instead of `Eff '[ M ] x -> m x`. This ends up 'pushing' all of the effects into `Eff '[ IO ] x` which you can run to get `IO x`.

Comment: .. in particular [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer-0.2.4.1/docs/Control-Monad-Freer.html#v:runNat) effects library has a function `runNat` which builds 'runners' with these types: `\x -> runNat (flip runDbT x) :: Member m r => Eff (DbT m ': r) x -> Eff r x`

Comment: @user2407038 can you add your comments as an answer so that I can try and accept it?

Comment: @user2407038 I'm wondering if this is possible using `extensible-effects` library. As far as I can see, it doesn't provide anything like Freer's `runM` or `runNat`.

Comment: @sinan `extensible-effects` essentially has the same interface as `freer`, just fewer 'helper' functions. I believe that you can write `runM` with `decomp` and `run` and you can write [`runNat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer-0.2.4.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-Freer.html#runNat) with `handleRelay` (exactly how it's done in freer) - note that `handleRelay` have slightly different types between the two libraries. I've never actually used `extensible-effects` so I can't be sure. (if you want to accept an answer, accept this one, and perhaps edit my comment into the end if you like :))